# Using Wrangler with MySQL: A server error occurred when testing the connection. Error: Exception occurred while handling request: string

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to connect a MySQL database via Google Cloud Data Fusion Wrangler. It's a very standard connection and I can connect and do every action with another tool (DBeaver). However, trying to connect with Wrangler, I am getting this message:

```
A server error occurred when testing the connection. Error: Exception occurred while handling request: string
```

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add [JDBC Driver](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-jdbc-drivers) name for connecting to MySQL Database and provide other parameters like Connection name and Connection String to setup the connection.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-jdbc-drivers

Once done, you will be able to select the uploaded driver from the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you have to use [JDBC Driver](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-jdbc-drivers) for connecting to MySQL database.You can use Public IP to setup connection to Wrangler.

**Following are the steps to connect to MySQL database using Wrangler**

- Go to Hub in the Cloud Fusion instance and and select the required JDBC Driver.
- Download the
  driver and deploy it.
- Go to Wranglers page and click on Add
  Connection if you are connecting to MySQL for the first time.
- Select
  the MySQL database from the list of databases provided in Wrangler.
- Add name and JDBC driver along with username, password and other connection arguments.
- Click on test connection to check the connectivity.

For more details you can check this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md).